# Converting Image into Grayscale C# Visual 14

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, picturebox

I am having a little trouble with converting image to gray-scale in C# via Microsoft visual

Currently I have my code set up that In my GUI I can resize the image,
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLyKr.png)
I want to be able to convert the shown image into gray-scale by click the button. Code below!. Once I press the gray-scale button my app freezes. Where am I going wrong

```
   private void buttonGrayscale_Scale(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmMyImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)PictureBox1.Image);
        bmMyImage=MakeGrayscale(bmMyImage);

        PictureBox1.Image = (Image)bmMyImage;
    }

    public static Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Bitmap original)
    {
        //make an empty bitmap the same size as orgininal
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

        for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
            {
                Color c = newBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);

                int r = c.R;
                int g = c.G;
                int b = c.B;
                int avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
                newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(avg, avg, avg));

            }
        }

        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Try to set up something like a progress indication then you'll probably see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want get pixel from original, not from empty bitmap?

```
Color c = original.GetPixel(i, j);
```

You cannot need convert bitmap to image.

```
private void buttonGrayscale_Scale(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmMyImage=MakeGrayscale(PictureBox1.Image);

        PictureBox1.Image=bmMyImage;
    }
```

And function is:

```
public static Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Image original)
...
```

Comment: Color c = original.GetPixel(i, j); this one line of code helped. Thank you